# file.choose() opens dialogue without file names on Windows

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

When I use `file.choose` or `choose.files` to select a file, the dialogue window shows folder icons but no text.

[image: Blank Window]

This problem did not occur previously. I did update RStudio not too long ago, but I am not sure if that is the cause. I am currently using R 4.1.1 and RStudio 2023.03.0 Build 386.

`file.choose` is in **base** and `choose.files` is in **utils**, so they should both be up to date. I see this behavior even in a new R process with no additional packages loaded, so I know that I am calling the functions in base R.

Comment: move the horizontal scroll bar

Comment: All the columns are blank, moving the scroll bar does not change anything.

Comment: Does the problem also arise when running R from the command line, rather than from RStudio? Have you tried upgrading R? We are already at 4.3.0, so your versions of `file.choose` and `choose.files` are not actually "up to date".

Comment: Excellent thought. The dialogue windows look fine when running from the R terminal command prompt. I will try installing most current version of R.

Comment: Updating to 4.2.3 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As per today, without having changed something, I also have this visual issue.
I ran `SurveyData <- readxl::read_excel(file.choose())`, and it shows a window to the right folder, but I can't see any names or even the text on the window buttons, like M Aurélio shows.

I have tried:

- Updating R (now 4.3.1)
- Updating RStudio (now 2023.06.2+561)
- Resetting graphics drivers
- Rebooting RStudio and rebooting my laptop

*Edit: Doing all of the above and rebooting again might have fixed it for me.*

Answer (score 1):

As no one has yet answered this question by putting the working solutions in an answer instead of a comment, I will copy some and add more possible solutions for @Faemaika who seems to have the same problem, but for who the stated solutions do not help.

Firstly, as Mikael Jagan stated, try running `base::file.choose()` from the command line, rather than from RStudio.
If this works well, try upgrading R to the latest version. It should be at least 4.3.0, but at the moment of writing we are in R 4.3.1 for which it should work too. Then, `file.choose` and `choose.files` are up to date enough.

Secondly, if this does not work, open the app 'file explorer' and keep it open while using the `file.choose` function in RStudio.

Thirdly, if the problem still persists, check if your RStudio file chooser is currently located to a path which is accessible. If you last opened a file to which the path is now depricated, the file chooser might struggle with opening any path at all. You can solve this by manually opening a random file by using `Ctrl + O` and clicking some random file. Then retry `file.choose`.

Fourthly, you might consider to reboot your pc/RStudio. This may work only after multiple times; do not give up too soon.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment from @Mikael Jagan, updating R solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, if you could successfully run the following command prior to the execution of the Shiny application, it would work like a charm...! Don't know why... :p

base::file.choose()

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34685320)