# file.choose() dialogue box is blank

Tags: r

When I use file.choose to select a file with RStudio, the dialog box is blank, with no text.

[image: Blank file.choose() window.]

I have recently updated RStudio to 2023.03.0 Build 386, and the problem did not occur previously.  This appears to be the same issues as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75892124/file-choose-opens-dialogue-without-file-names-on-windows?newreg=da6200585119442e85df27ac9cbdaac7) user, but in that case updating to the latest version of R solved the issue (that didn't work for me).

I am using:

R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

If I open R (not RStudio) and try it, it works fine.  I've tried rolling back to previous versions of both R and RStudio without luck.  This is happening sporadically to a colleague, who is often able to restart their computer and the text comes back, but then at some point disappears again.  What else can I try?

Comment: Isn't the file-open dialog provided by the OS? My win11 open-file dialog looks different (no surprise). Does your open-file dialog look better/normal from other apps? For me, this open-file dialog looks the same as one from Excel (_File > Open > Browse_).

Comment: But the text is missing - those icons should have file names next to them.  Also look at the buttons - those should say open and cancel.